# Katz centrality convergence

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory

[Katz centrality computing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rwiml.jpg)

I reported the formulation used for the computation of the Katz centrality in the picture (linked up). I have some questions:

- The factor "alpha" is the attenuation factor and it is used for the convergence of the algorithm. Why the value of this factor have to is minor of 1/rho (where rho is the spectral radius of matrix A)?

> In matrix terms, Eq. (7.8) can be written x = αAx + β1, (7.9) where 1 is the vector (1, 1, 1 . . .). Rearranging for x, we find that x = β(I − αA)^{−1} · 1. As we have said, we normally don’t care about the absolute magnitude of the centrality, only about which vertices have high or low centrality values, so the overall multiplier β is unimportant. For convenience we usually set β = 1, giving x = (I − αA)^{−1} · 1. (7.10) This centrality measure was first proposed by Katz in 1953 [169] and we will refer to it as the Katz centrality. The Katz centrality differs from ordinary eigenvector centrality in the important respect of having a free parameter α, which governs the balance between the eigenvector term and the constant term in Eq. (7.8). If we wish to make use of the Katz centrality we must first choose a value for this constant. In doing so it is important to understand that α cannot be arbitrarily large. If we let α → 0, then only the constant term survives in Eq. (7.8) and all vertices have the same centrality β (which we have set to 1). As we increase α from zero the centralities increase and eventually there comes a point at which they diverge. This happens at the point where (I − αA)^{−1} diverges in Eq. (7.10), i.e., when det(I − αA) passes through zero. Rewriting this condition as det(A − α^{−1}I) = 0, (7.11) we see that it is simply the characteristic equation whose roots α^{−1} are equal to the eigenvalues of the adjacency matrix. As α increases, the determinant first crosses zero when α^{-1} = κ1, the largest eigenvalue of A, or alternatively when α = 1/κ1. Thus, we should choose a value of α less than this if we wish the expression for the centrality to converge

- If the matrix A have all the eigenvalues equal to 0 the spectral radius is equal to 0. So, is it always possible to calculate centrality? How do I choose the alpha value?